# Event change:visible not fired when map reaches layer minResolution or maxResolution

Tags: openlayers

I'm listening to a layer's event `change:visible`. However it does not get fired when the resolution changes.

I.E. my layer as a minimum resolution of 0.5964957884324376. If I zoom past it, even though my layer is no longer displayed on the map, the event is not fired and its visible state is still `true`.

How can I detect my layer is no longer displayed because of its min/max resolution setup ?

Comment: need minimum code on fiddle

Comment: Some code would not help here. My question is : how can I know a layer is no longer visible on the map ?

Comment: The event change:visible is not fired, because visibility is not changed if the layer is outside min/max resolution limits. Did anybody find a solution to this? Here is a jsfiddle with the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/beke60od/